# Firefox Add-on SDK Tab Open Flashes

Tags: firefox-addon

When I open a new tab it first flashes white then puts up my page. I'd like to not have the flash. I was thinking I could load the tab in the background then switch to that tab once it was fully loaded (so no white flash).

I use *inBackground: true* to create the tab and load it (but not switch to it yet). But now once I have done this how can I programmatically switch to it?

If there is a way to open a tab directly but first wait until it is rendered so it does not flash that would be great too. But *tabs.open* does not seem to do that.

The bellow code is modified from
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Getting_Started_(jpm)

```
var buttons = require('sdk/ui/button/action');
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");

var button = buttons.ActionButton({
  id: "mozilla-link",
  label: "Visit Mozilla",
  icon: {
   "16": "./icon-16.png",
   "32": "./icon-32.png",
   "64": "./icon-64.png"
  },
  onClick: handleClick
});

function handleClick(state) {
  tabs.open({ url: "http://localhost/HomePage/", inBackground: true });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See official [tabs API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/tabs#activate%28%29) documentation

> **activate()**
>
> Makes this tab active, which will bring this tab to the foreground.

Comment: Thanks... activate() solved it!. I used activate() like this: tabs.open({ url: "some url", inBackground: true, onLoad: function (tab) { tab.activate(); } });